# Is there a function in C to get the current process's virtual runtime on Linux?

Tags: c, linux, process, scheduler, scheduling

**TL;DR:**
What would be the best way to:

1. Get the current process;
2. Access its PCB;
3. Access and return its `vruntime` value?

I'm trying to implement a new system call (in C) which will return the virtual runtime of the current process.
The virtual runtime is stored in the `vruntime` field in the process's PCB, but I couldn't find how to access it.

I've been trying to find a way using the process's PID or the process name itself without success.
Is there a way to get the process as a `struct task_struct` variable and access the `vruntime`field?

Answer (score 0):

There is already one, [`getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &rusage)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrusage.2.html), implemented in [kernel/sys.c:getrusage()](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/kernel/sys.c).

Answer (score 0):

Your system call will be running in kernel mode in the context of the thread that invoked it, so the following expression will get the current process task_struct:

```
current_thread_info() -> task
```

You can then read the vruntime field to a buffer provided by the user, using `copy_to_user` or similar for safety with respect to untrusted addresses from the caller.